# ng build error with property not found

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

I define an object of type any in Typescript but when i build with `ng build --prod --aot` it shows the property not exist `auth_user` and `auth_password`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'http://localhost:8033',
  token_name: 'X-Auth-Token',
  auth_user: 'X-Auth-Username',
  auth_password: 'X-Auth-Password'
};

authenticate(user: User) {
    var payload:{[x: string]: any} = {}
    payload[environment.auth_user] = user.username;
    payload[environment.auth_password] = user.password;
    return this.apiService.post("/authenticate", {}, new Headers(payload))
}
```

i also tried

```
var payload:any = {
      [environment.auth_password]:user.password,
      [environment.auth_user] : user.username
    }
```

but with no luck.
Any solution will be appreciated.

Error detail

```
ERROR in /home/vikram/code/angular/start/src/app/user/services/user.service.ts (26,20): Property 'auth_password' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; api_url: string; }'.
ERROR in /home/vikram/code/angular/start/src/app/user/services/user.service.ts (27,20): Property 'auth_user' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; api_url: string; }'.
```

here is my complete service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService implements OnInit {


  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private jwtService: JwtService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  saveUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.post("/user", user);
  }
  authenticate(user: User) {
    var payload:any = {
      [environment.auth_password]:user.password,
      [environment.auth_user] : user.username
    }
    return this.apiService.post("/authenticate", {}, new Headers(payload))
  }
}
```

Comment: it works fine in dev environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two file in the environment folder
`environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`

And i was executing command `ng build --prod --aot`

so it was taking `environment.prod.ts` while building

but in environment.prod.ts these properties were not defined since i never build for production after adding these property to environment.prod.ts
It is working find

Answer (score 0):

Try the object's definition this way. Exchange '=' by ':'

```
export const environment: {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'http://localhost:8033',
  token_name: 'X-Auth-Token',
  auth_user: 'X-Auth-Username',
  auth_password: 'X-Auth-Password'
};
```